Infinite loop between "loadScene" and "initialize", causing our FXML file to be loaded over and over again
Background for our application (can be skipped if u dont think it is relevant):
We are creating an application for kids with autism to identify and understanding gestures and facial expressions. We do this by presenting a story and then give them a task to switch between different gestures and facial expressions to try to plot the expression and gesture they think the character in that story has or felt like. We then have a reflection page where the kid and the teacher reflect or discuss the choices the autistic kid made and they can then go back and try different facial expressions and gestures. If they're happy with the result they can end the task and the first story is completed and the second story will unlock in the library. Our story will only consist of one character throughout both stories. Just in different scenarios.
Our problem with the code:
Our code right now is not opening our FXML file and instead printing the FXML file path in an infinite loop, and we think it is because of an issue in the initialize method of the StoryController class. Specifically, the loadScene method is being called repeatedly in a loop, causing the FXML file to be loaded over and over again (we think.) So how should we fix this? We've tried asking various AI tools and looked up the FXML documentation in Java and such. One time the loop was randomly fixed and then we got a nullpointerException to our URL for our Story FXML file.
We have few other classes, but they're not constructed yet, so this is the first step in our implementation proces, and we can't really go any further before we fix this issue... Any help would be appriciated. Thanks
This is our StoryController code with the loadscene and initialize method in:
package PACKAGE_NAME.src.main.project.classes;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class StoryController {
    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label storyDescriptionLabel;

    private int currentStory = 0;

    private List<Story> stories = new ArrayList<>();

    public StoryController() {
        loadStoriesFromFile("src/main/project/classes/Stories/Story.txt");
    }

    public List<Story> getStories() {
        return stories;
    }

    /**
     * @param filename This method reads the stories from a file and adds them to the stories list.
     *                 It seperates the title and the story description by a comma.
     */
    private void loadStoriesFromFile(String filename) {
        // The method uses a try-with-resources statement to ensure that the BufferedReader is closed after it's no longer needed. This is a good practice to avoid resource leaks.
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            String line;
            Story previousStory = null;
            // While loop to read the file line by line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Each line is split into parts using a comma (,) as the delimiter.
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                // The first part is considered the title, and the second part is considered the story description.
                String title = parts[0];
                String storyDescription = parts[1];

                // A new Story object is created using the extracted title and story description.
                Story story = new Story(title, storyDescription);
                // Then add the newly created story object to the "stories" ArrayList.
                stories.add(story);
            }
            // If any IOException occurs during the file reading process, it's caught and the error message is printed to the console.
            //  IOException is typically thrown when an error occurs while performing input or output operations, such as reading or writing to a file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * if the story list is not empty, it sets the title and story description of the first story
     * in the list to the corresponding labels.
     */

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // Check if the stories ArrayList is not empty
        if (!stories.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < stories.size(); i++) {
                String title = stories.get(i).getTitle();
                titleLabel.setText(title);
                storyDescriptionLabel.setText(stories.get(i).getStoryDescription());

                // Load the scene for the story
                loadScene(currentStory + 1);

            }

        }
    }

    private void loadScene(int storyNumber) {
        try {
            // Append the story number to the ".fxml"
            String fxmlFile = "/Story" + storyNumber + ".fxml";
            System.out.println("Loading FXML file: " + fxmlFile);
            URL url = getClass().getResource(fxmlFile);
            System.out.println(url);


            // Load the FXML file
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);

            // Get the current stage
            Stage stage = (Stage) titleLabel.getScene().getWindow();

            // Set the new scene
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


Furthermore, we also have this LibraryController class if relevant:
The library in our application is for the user to choose between the stories. (we are only going to implement two)
package PACKAGE_NAME.src.main.project.classes;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LibraryController {
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    @FXML
    public void spil(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Story1.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}




Post the relevant FXML files. I don't quite understand the structure here: you have multiple StoryNNN.fxml files which basically do the same thing, but with different data? That would not seem to be a sensible way to structure things.

Create a button and use it to go to the then next ``Scene. Remove that for-loop`.

@James_D
Yes we have two Story.fxml files. (Story1.fxml and Story2.fxml). Since we only plan on using two stories, how is that not a sensible way to structure it?

I'm not sure I understand the issue very well, but it seems like you're calling the loadScene method inside a loop, but it's always loading from the same value... currentStory + 1, and currentStory is always set to zero and does not change its value throughout the program

Well we tried changing that, but now we just get the same error all the time: our titleLabel is null.
